# UK visa refusal wrong reason, who to contact

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, ukrainian-citizens

Hello i hope some can help, I will try to be brief.

My girlfriend applied for a tourist visa for UK from Ukraine with me giving full sponsorship. When she went to visa centre 4 hours before her appointment to get her paperwork translated (even thou i told her to get this done somewhere else a friend advised her to do it at Visa ctr) she was told no need as "my" documents were the important ones and her application was taken then and there.

Her Visa was refused but the main reason states because she has no dependants but it clearly states in her application she has a 4 yr old boy and she would obviously (in most cases anyway) want to return to him.

We have met 4 times this year with me flying to Ukraine and also we went to Greece for holiday and after refusal we went to Gdansk, Poland for a week.

Is there anyone i can contact about this just to have another look at it, i have read on here about contacting the Embassy is that the Embassy in Kiev and if so how or has anyone any better advice?

[image: Refusal letter] 
[image]

Comment: The main reason isn't the lack of dependents: all the reasons are "main". I'm very surprised that they advised your friend that your documents are the important ones, since that is exactly the opposite of what everybody else says.

Comment: I also was very surprised as it states on all sites and Visa site that all foreign documents should be translated into English. I just wish i had been there as i would have insisted on it being done also they lost the cost of it.

Comment: So her yearly income is equal to the cost of her proposed holiday? 12 x 95 GBP = ~ GBP 1200.

Comment: Yes Rodney, but all her costs i am paying, it would not be £1200 as the only real costs would be her flights. The main thing is the statement in the refusal that says she has no dependants but her application says she does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should email the UKVI center that processed your application directly and send a CC to the British Embassy in your country. That should resolve your issue. (based on a friend's experience).

Comment: Hi greatone, my country is UK but would it not be the British Embassy in Ukraine that i need to contact or even Warsaw as they seem to be where the Visa decision is made?

Comment: @tony martin it won't hurt to send a copy of the email to both.