# Refusal of a visit visa for a resident of Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, saudi-arabia

I am an expat who's been living in Saudi Arabia for more than 30 years. I have a valid 5-year visa to the UK. I wanted to take my family (4 members including my wife) on a vacation to the UK and this is their first time traveling outside KSA and my home country.

I just moved to a new job (I wasn't between jobs as I moved immediately) recently and the pay in my new job is around £9,000 per month, which is the same as my previous job. Unfortunately, my bank statement does not include the first month's pay from my new employer.

I got the attached letter and I am aiming to change the following. I need your expertise and advice:

1. I will change it from 2 years to 6 months, as I applied for 2 years.
2. I will include a reference name and number in my employer letter to backup the first point.
3. I asked the landlord to share with me a rental contract. However this will only be  1 month old on my travel date. Any recommendation regarding the ties to Saudi Arabia and that I will return?

[image]

Comment: *I am an expert who is living in Saudi Arabia*: Did you mean **expat**?

Comment: "Published for Home Office staff on 15 February 2017"???

Comment: Yes expat sorry for the typo

Comment: @henning Makholm: I think this footnote which used for all letters issued by Home Office until they change it and give it a different/new reference . I applied in mid of June 2018

Comment: What is the reason the visa office was unable to contact your new employer? Did you give them the correct contact details?

Comment: @DJClayworth, The letter does not include a particular HR Personal contact details but only the land line number which is usually answered by an operator for a company that has more than +4,000 employees

Comment: If someone calls the company landline and says "I need to verify employment details" the operator usually transfers them to HR, since that is what they are paid for.

Comment: Don’t forget that language can be a barrier !

Comment: @HenningMakholm [It seems to be in use for many letters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103393/uk-visa-refusal-wrong-reason-who-to-contact)

Comment: Any recommend answers for the particular case